# How do I loop a function if a certain element is not present in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to loop a function in selenium.

So as long as DisplayName on the web page is not "fish", I want to the program to type in "fish" and press enter until the display name is "fish" and then I want the program to stop.

Currently, the program keeps running and typing in "fishfishfishfishfish" for the display name.

```
 DisplayName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="DisplayName"]""")
    while (DisplayName != "fish"):
        DisplayName.send_keys("fish"")
        DisplayName.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Comment: You don't refresh the value in `DisplayName` in the while loop. After you type in 'fish' get the new value of the field so the while loop has something new to test against.

Comment: 4 Questions. 1) What is the criteria for the `DisplayName on the web page to be "fish"`? 2) What do we need to do for that? 3) Are you trying to type "fish" in the same element or some other element? 4) Would pressing `Enter` change the **DisplayName** to `"fish"`?

Comment: The same element. Pressing enter does change the DisplayName to "fish". First, the element gets filled once the keys are sent, and then enter is pressed to save it, but then the program keeps going and typing an extra fish each time when it's already filled. I just want to know how to check if the element == a certain string, for it to do something (in this case, stop.)

Comment: `DisplayName` is the element, not the text. Use `DisplayName.text` or `DisplayName.get_atttribute("value")` if it is an `INPUT` tag, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing user input is mirrored from one input to another with Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314026/testing-user-input-is-mirrored-from-one-input-to-another-with-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear` method to clear the field before start typying in. 
Also use a constant wait for a short time - in AJAX pages there may be some javascript fired when a field value changes, give this javascript some time to execute (I don't know how to do it in phyton, in example below i used `sleep( 1 second)`, in Java we are using `Thread.sleep( 1000 )` to sleep for a 1 second.

```
DisplayName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="DisplayName"]""")
    while (DisplayName != "fish"):
        DisplayName.clear()
        DisplayName.send_keys("fish"")
        DisplayName.send_keys(u'\ue007')
        sleep( 1 second)
```

Comment: `DisplayName` is the element, not the text contained. you will want to use `while (DisplayName.text != "fish"):` or if it's an `INPUT`, you will want to check the value of the element instead.